# How do I sort file paths based on multiple embedded numbers?

Tags: bash, sorting

I have run a program to generate results with different parameters, `R`, `C` and `RP`, reflected in the *directory name* of the output files, all named `results.txt`.

For instance, in directory name `params_R_7_C_16_RP_0`, the `7` is the value of parameter `R`, `16` is the value of parameter `C` and `0` is the value of parameter `RP`.

I want to get all `results.txt` files in the current directory tree, sorted by the embedded values of `R`,`C` and `RP` in their hosting directories.

I first use the following command to get the `results.txt` files that I want to parse:

```
find ./ -name "results.txt"
```

and the output is:

```
./params_R_11_C_9_RP_0/results.txt 
./params_R_7_C_9_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_7_C_4_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_11_C_16_RP_0/results.txt 
./params_R_9_C_4_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_5_C_9_RP_0/results.txt 
./params_R_9_C_25_RP_0/results.txt 
./params_R_7_C_16_RP_0/results.txt 
./params_R_5_C_25_RP_0/results.txt 
./params_R_5_C_16_RP_0/results.txt 
./params_R_11_C_4_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_9_C_16_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_7_C_25_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_11_C_25_RP_0/results.txt 
./params_R_5_C_4_RP_0/results.txt 
./params_R_9_C_9_RP_0/results.txt
```

and I tried the following sort command:

```
find ./ -name "results.txt" | sort
```

which results in *lexical* sorting:

```
./params_R_11_C_16_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_11_C_25_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_11_C_4_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_11_C_9_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_5_C_16_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_5_C_25_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_5_C_4_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_5_C_9_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_7_C_16_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_7_C_25_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_7_C_4_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_7_C_9_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_9_C_16_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_9_C_25_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_9_C_4_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_9_C_9_RP_0/results.txt
```

But what I actually want is selective *numerical* sorting: first by `R` value, then `C`, then `RP`:

```
./params_R_5_C_4_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_5_C_9_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_5_C_16_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_5_C_25_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_7_C_4_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_7_C_9_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_7_C_16_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_7_C_25_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_9_C_4_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_9_C_9_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_9_C_16_RP_0/results.txt
./params_R_9_C_25_RP_0/results.txt
...
```

I considered padding the embedded numbers (e.g., `params_R_005_C_004_RP_0`) when generating the paths list, but that would require an additional processing step, which I want to avoid.

Can the desired sorting be achieved directly?

Comment: @JakeGould, thank you for improving this question!

Comment: Could you please shorten the input and output sample data a little and also make it clearer what the objective is? Based on the accepted answer, it seems that you want the paths sorted by _numerical_ components in them (all the text components appear to be the same).

Comment: @mklement0, yes, in the `params_R_7_C_16_RP_0`, the `7` is the value of `R`, the `16` is the value of `C` and the `0` is the value of 'RP'. I have run a program to generate these results with the different parameters(i.e. the `R`, `C` and `RP`). Then, I should parse these experimental results to make an analysis.

Comment: @mklement0, I have shorten the question for clearer viewing. Please kindly check it.

Comment: Thanks for shortening; perhaps you could also add the explanation for the `R`, `C`, and `RP` values _directly to the answer_; if I understand correctly, you want to sort by the numbers associated with these fields (first by `R` value, then by `C` value, then by `RP` value).

Comment: @mklement0, absolutely right! I have enriched the question with more description. Please kindly check it! Thanks.

Comment: FYI -- the easiest way to avoid this problem in the first place would be to zero-pad numbers in your filenames; if they were all named as `R_009_C_025_RP_000` (using enough digits to not run a risk of overflow), this would be a nonissue, because numeric sort and alpha sort would have the same results. `printf` with formats such as `%03d` make it easy to generate such names.

Comment: @Nicolas: Thanks for your update; I took the liberty of making further edits to clarify your intent - I hope I succeeded.

Comment: @mklement0, OK, thank you for persistent improvement of this question!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, absolutely right! I'll use the `%03d` when generating the  directory name. This will make things easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `-V` flag for `sort`

```
find ./ -name "results.txt" | sort -V
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! It works! I should learn more about the commands.

Comment: ...by the way, `sort -V` isn't a POSIX option, so it's not guaranteed to be available on non-GNU systems. Likely worth noting, if your scripts might need to be portable elsewhere.

Comment: As @CharlesDuffy notes, `-V` is a _GNU_ extension to `sort`. Its purpose is to perform _version number-based_ sorting. It's apparently flexible enough to sort based on embedded numbers separated by _any_ non-word character (not just `.`, as in version numbers, but also, e.g., `_`, as in this case). Caveat: all _non-numeric parts_ of the input lines -  including the separators - must be identical.

Answer (score 5):

If you use *GNU* `sort` (a recent-enough version), [@Fabricator's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24196809/45375), based on GNU `sort`'s `-V` option, is by far the simplest solution.

Otherwise, try this **POSIX-compliant solution**:

```
 find . -name 'results.txt' | sort -n -t _ -k3,3 -k5,5 -k 7,7
```

- `-n` specifies *numeric* sorting
- `-t _` splits the input line into fields based on separator char. `_`
- `-k3,3 -k5,5 -k 7,7` sorts the input based first on field 3, then field 5, then field 7, corresponding to the `R`, `C` and `RP` values.
  (Note that using `-k` with a *single* number - e.g., `-k3` - would instead result in sorting *from* field 3 *through the remainder of the line*).

Comment: The command in this answer works fine! Thanks for the detail explanations.

Answer (score 0):

try `find ./ -name "results.txt" | sort -k 3 -t _ -n -k 5 -n`

Comment: thank you. I'm not sure the meaning of the command above. I guess the parameters `-k 3 -t _ -n -k 5 -n` let the `sort` command sort the file names according to the characters between the char `_`, but I have tried the command, it couldn't output the desired result.

Comment: -t is to specify the field separator which is _. -k 3 -n will sort the 3rd field numerically and again -k 5 -n will again sort the 5th field numerically. It works fine for me.